# Marascuilo procedure in R

Tags: r, statistical-test

I'm conducting the marascuilio procedure in order to compare differences between proportions.
I'm using the following code (copied and adapted from [this tutorial](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc474.r):

```
## Set the proportions of interest.
p = c(0.3481, 0.1730, 0.4788)
N = length(p)
value = critical.range = c()

## Compute critical values.
for (i in 1:(N-1))
{ for (j in (i+1):N)
{
  value = c(value,(abs(p[i]-p[j])))
  critical.range = c(critical.range,
                     sqrt(qchisq(.95,3))*sqrt(p[i]*(1-p[i])/12000 + p[j]*(1-p[j])/12000))
}
}
round(cbind(value,critical.range),3)
```

I need that the output will print also the labels of the categories (e.g. which categories are exactly being compared).

So if the categories are listed in a seperated vector, e.g. `categories <- c("cat1", "cat2", cat"3)`, the comparisons are `cat1-cat2` , `cat1-cat3`, and `cat2-cat3`.

How can i append these labels to my output?

```
    value critical.range
[1,] 0.175          0.016
[2,] 0.131          0.018
[3,] 0.306          0.016
```

Comment: What should the output dataframe look like in the example above?

Comment: I added an example, so basically another column should be added and carry the information about categories comparisons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful about the denominator in your calculation of the critical.range (12000)...that is based on your sample size for EACH category - if you don't have 12000 observations for each category, then that needs to be adjusted -if you have far fewer than 12000 observations, your critical values are probably much lower than what that function gave you (and consequently, you should have fewer sign. differences).

Comment: The question asked was *How can i append these labels to my output?* This answer does not address the question. It should be a comment instead (which you can do once you get 50 reputation).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
## Set the proportions of interest.
p = c(0.3481, 0.1730, 0.4788)
N = length(p)
value = critical.range = tag = c()
categories <- c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3")

## Compute critical values.
for (i in 1:(N-1)){ 
    for (j in (i+1):N){

    value <- c(value,(abs(p[i]-p[j])))
    critical.range = c(critical.range,
                       sqrt(qchisq(.95,N-1))*sqrt(p[i]*(1-p[i])/12000 + p[j]*(1-p[j])/12000))
    tag = c(tag, paste(categories[i], categories[j], sep = "-"))

    }
}
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(value,critical.range, tag), stringsAsFactors = F)
df$value <- round(as.numeric(df$value),3)
df$critical.range <- round(as.numeric(df$critical.range),3)
```

Output:

```
 value critical.range       tag
1 0.175          0.016 cat1-cat2
2 0.131          0.018 cat1-cat3
3 0.306          0.016 cat2-cat3
```

Comment: Great. I'm adding `df$significance <- ifelse(df$value>df$critical.range,"yes","no")
` to the `df` so it also will indicate whether the comparison is significant or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Python translation of the R code, with 4 categories and different sample sizes (n) per category.
The code was kindly translated from R to Python by the Bing AI assistant with slight corrections by me

```
import math
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import chi2

p = [0.681818182, 0.816513761, 0.65625, 0.518518519]
n = [22, 109, 32, 27]
N = len(p)
value = []
critical_range = []
tag = []
categories = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"]
critical_value = chi2.ppf(0.95, 4)

for i in range(N-1):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        value.append(abs(p[i] - p[j]))
        critical_range.append(math.sqrt(critical_value) * math.sqrt((p[i] * 
                (1 - p[i]) / n[i]) + (p[j] * (1 - p[j]) / n[j])))
        tag.append(categories[i] + "-" + categories[j])

df = pd.DataFrame({"value": value, "critical.range": critical_range, "tag": tag})
df["value"] = df["value"].round(3)
df["critical.range"] = df["critical.range"].round(3)
df["significance"] = df.apply(lambda row: "yes" if row["value"] > 
row["critical.range"] else "no", axis=1)
print(df)
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [scipy.stats](/questions/tagged/scipy.stats) [bing](/questions/tagged/bing) [ai](/questions/tagged/ai)